# Strict standards: Declaration of DatabaseAccess::get() should be compatible with medoo::get($table, $join = NULL, $column = NULL, $where = NULL)

Tags: php, medoo

I am encountering this error when trying to run a site using WAMP.

But it works fine on my LAMP VM.

The parent function has this signature:

```
public function get($table, $join = null, $column = null, $where = null)
{
```

And it is extended like so:

```
class DatabaseAccess extends Medoo
{
    public function get($table, $columns, $where = null)
    {
        return parent::get($table, $columns, $where);
    }
```

Is WAMP more strict with this or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overriding the method with a different signature. This would broke inheritance if was allowed. Why would you extend a database adapter at all? Just use it as is or wrap in a new class instead of inheritance if you want a simpler interface.

**Edit**: BTW You can probably fix this by disabling strict standards.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_STRICT)
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Unfortunately I don't have that option. This is a fairly big system which I have recently taken over and I would rather get the extended class working than replace every use of it in the whole system. Why does this work on the VM though?

Comment: `error_reporting` probably disabled on VM. At 5.4.0 E_STRICT became part of E_ALL.

Comment: That seems to have solved it. I'll use that as a temporary workaround. Really appreciate the help